# Tensor product of $k$-algebras, center, isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ be two $k$-algebras of finite dimension, where $k$ is a field. Here, $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily commutative. Do we have that$$Z(A \otimes_k B) \cong Z(A) \otimes_k Z(B),$$where $Z(-)$ is the center?

Comment: Yes, and you don't need that $A, B$ are finite-dimensional, although you do need that $k$ is a field: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137584/two-infinite-dimensional-algebras-such-that-the-center-of-their-tensor-product-i

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I read the proof and I see that it requires algebras to be unitial. It would be nice to generalise it to non-unitial ones or find a counterexample.